# How to certify an eMMC write under Linux

Tags: linux, persistent

I want to make sure that before my program continues the data that I have written to the eMMC memory is actually stored in the flash memory and not in the cache of the eMMC.
What driver for eMMC that runs under LInux support that feature.
I have no intention of writing a driver myself at least not now. As far as I can tell by reading the eMMC specification it is possible to flush the cache.

Regards CT

Comment: Then your program should be using userspace API and not rely on the driver.  The driver isn't aware of any fs cache and is a few layers removed from userspace syscalls, so how would you even correlate/track the I/O operations?  See https://www.slideshare.net/rampalliraj/linux-kernel-mmc-storage-driver-overview?next_slideshow=1